# How to download attachment of an email through Azure data factory

Tags: office365, azure-data-factory

I was completed the app registration  process in my azure portal for office 365 and i am able to connect with that credentials to office 365 but i didn't perform any linking operations for my outlook mail.
Also i created one dataset and copy data activity to perform attachments download task. But i am not able download any attachments and I am getting error for Microsoft graph data error.

So, anyone help me to solve my issue( How to link office 365 in Azure active directory app registration process)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am not able download any attachments and I am getting error for Microsoft graph data error.

You actually need to give `Mail.Read` API permission to your Service Principal ID. Follow the below steps to implement the same.

1. In Azure Active Directory, go to App registration. Choose your App which you have created.
2. Go to `API permissions` and click on `+ Add a permission`

[image]

3. Select the `Application permission` option and search for `Mail.Read` permission. Click on the checkbox and then select `update permission` at the bottom.

[image]

You will see the `Mail.Read` permission under your Microsoft graph as shown in image 1 above.

Comment: Thanks for replay @Utkarsh pal. I was given api permissions by following ur Steps. But, my portal and Office 365 tenants are in different zone. will it be a problem? 
After run the pipeline I am  getting again Microsoft Graph data  Privileges  Error.
"Office365 data loading failed to execute. office365LoadErrorType: PermanentError. The tenant admin did not opt-in to Microsoft Graph Data Connect. Please ask your tenant admin to opt-in to this service. To opt-in, look for settings for Microsoft Graph Data Connect preview. "
If both  accounts will be in same tenants.Then how can I achieve?

Comment: Could you please provide a document to download attachment from mail through Azure data factory. If you have any. @Utkarsh Pal